# Is static init repeated for each request?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I've been assuming that static initialization (e.g. for my persistence library) will persist between requests for a given instance?  Suddenly it occurred to me that maybe I'm wrong - maybe my app's init is redone for each request even on a warm instance.

Here's why I'm asking:

I have a request handler (it happens to be a Google Endpoint, but I don't think that is relevant) that receives a list of entities and saves them.

The entities can be any of 20 different types, so my static initialization 'registers' all 20 different entity types.  I happen to be using objectify, so it looks like this:

```
@Api(name = "myendpoint")
public class MyEndpoint {
  static {
    ObjectifyService.register( EntityOne.class );
    ObjectifyService.register( EntityTwo.class );
    ... x20
  }
```

If it is doing all this 'registering' for each  request then I had better change this to only register for the entities needed for the request.

(On the other hand, if I'm right and my static init is only done when creating a new instance then I should put as much initialization as I can into the static init.)

Comment: Please don't do anything that will give me points - just realized I'm at 3333!

Comment: You're better off avoiding initialising objectify inside a static init block - you need to add translators before the classes and objectify does not apply any thread safety to the factory when registering. In addition, this way can make it painful to debug/hotload locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static initializer blocks are run once when the class is being loaded.

Comment: Yes, but then my question becomes about the class loading.  So I think you are confirming that the loading of my app's classes (and their static init) only happen once per instance and persist between requests.

Comment: @Tom It's unlikely, but possible, that the "instance" unloads all your classes and reloads them, somewhere in the lifecycle of the instance. However that shouldn't cause any problem; to your application, it's like the instance is reloaded.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu Okay good, so then I won't worry about doing lots of static init (within reason, of course).  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, static initialization blocks are only run when the class is being loaded.  That means that it happens only once per GAE instance.

Something else worth considering:  It is often better to register these classes with Ofy via your own Objectify service class, and then use that to access Objectify functionality.  See https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices ... That ensures that the blocks are run before any datastore access happens.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking I should switch to the way you suggest, also to avoid repeating the same initialization code (the list of registers) in each of app's entry points.